# Swift service call, handling response

Tags: swift

I am writing the iOS application using swift 4.2. I am making a service call to logout user.
I need to know where to use main thread (DispatchQueue.main.async).
Here is my code:

```
    private func handleLogoutCellTap() {
        logoutUseCase?.logout() { [weak self] (result) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case let (.success(didLogout)):
                didLogout ? self.handleSuccessfullLogout() : self.handleLogoutError(with: nil)
            case let (.failure(error)):
                self.handleLogoutError(with: error)
            }
        }
    }
```

logoutUseCase?.logout() makes a service call and returns @escaping completion. Should I use DispatchQueue.main.async on this whole handleLogoutCellTap() function or just in a handling segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the control to `main thread` wherever you're updating the *UI* after receiving the response of `logout`.

If `handleSuccessfullLogout()` and `handleLogoutError(with:)` methods perform any *UI* operation, you can embed the whole `switch statement` in `DispatchQueue.main.async`, i,e.

```
private func handleLogoutCellTap() {
    logoutUseCase?.logout() { [weak self] (result) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //here.....
            switch result {
                //rest of the code....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I perform some actions on UI after receiving response and I will put whole switch statement in DispatchQueue.main.async. Thanks for an answer!